# What is the weight of the batteries on the e-Fan?

Tags: e-fan

Airbus' [own (early) page](http://www.highflyer.airbus-group.com/04_2013_efan_and_ethrust.html) with technical data about the e-Fan provides some information about the batteries.

It can, for instance, be calculated that they hold approx. 19kWh of energy if you accept a somewhat simplistic calculation by multiplying number of cells (120) with capacity (40A ) and voltage (4V).

What I can't find is information about the weight of these batteries. Is this information available somewhere or can it be reasonably estimated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The weight of the battery is [mentioned here](http://aviationweek.com/farnborough-2014/airbus-enters-e-plane-light-aircraft-market):

> Power is provided by 127 kg. of 250-volt lithium-ion polymer batteries
>   from Kokam in South Korea built into the wing.

A slightly different weight is [specified here](http://insideevs.com/eads-debuts-electric-e-fan-airplane-at-2013-paris-air-show-wvideo/):

> ... E-Fan has two lithium-polymer battery packs weighing 65 kg each.

I could not find which Kokam battery is being used on the e-fan, but [this page has specifications](http://www.cleancarb.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=38&layout=blog&Itemid=57) for all of their batteries.

Answer (score 5):

Slightly adjusting your energy estimate (3.6V × 40A × 120 Cells = 17280Wh vs original 19000 Wh), taking an [energy density](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/whats_the_best_battery) of 125Wh/kg for a high quality battery, it can be estimated:

$$\frac{17280}{125}=138\text{kg}$$

which I think sounds reasonable for a plane with a empty weight of around 500kg.

Comment: Matching this with Farhan's answer, I'd say that's a pretty close estimate!

Comment: Nice estimate and thanks for the link, very interesting.